# VS code 1.11.1 doesn't start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently updated VS code to 1.11.1 and it doesn't open. Here's what I get for

```
> code --verbose

cpk@hires104:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ code --verbose
Rejected cached data from file: /home/cpk/.config/Code/CachedData/b41ce30beb0cfd031094b05289558eaf-main.code
Rejected cached data from file: /home/cpk/.config/Code/CachedData/1ca6adb78ecf5501a9711dbe232db186-main.nls.code
Error: listen EPERM /home/cpk/.config/Code/1.11.1-main.sock
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1240:19)
    at listen (net.js:1289:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1378:5)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:107896
    at new n.Class.derive._oncancel (/usr/ Object.p [as serve] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:107826)
    at o (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:307746)
    at te (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:308817)share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:54249)
    at Object.p [as serve] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:107826)
    at o (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:307746)
    at te (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:308817)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove cache data?

Comment: Yes I did. But it still was showing the same error